# Quasar q-tabs: how to dynamically show/hide q-tab by code?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

There is a dropdownlist, if user choose a option, some q-tab-panel will show/hide to make a response. But how can I dynamically set the q-tab-panel show/hide by code? Hope someone can make suggestions here. Thanks

```
             <q-select filled
                        v-model="datasource.datasourcetype"
                        :options="datasource.options"
                        option-value="value"
                        option-label="label"
                        emit-value
                        map-options
                        :label="ui.datasourcetype" />
              <q-tabs v-model="dataEntryTab"
                      dense
                      class="bg-grey-2 text-teal"
                      align="left">
                <q-tab name="tabCustomized" v-if="dataentry.showOptionsTab" icon="mail" :label="ui.datasourceOptions" />
                <q-tab name="tabEntryInfo" v-if="dataentry.showDataEntryTab" icon="alarm" :label="ui.datasourceEntryInfo" />
                <q-tab name="tabCascadeField" v-if="dataentry.showCascadeFieldTab" icon="movie" :label="ui.datasourceCascadeField" />
              </q-tabs>
             <q-tab-panels v-model="dataEntryTab" animated>
                <q-tab-panel name="tabCustomized">
                  <q-input :label="ui.dataentryOptions"
                           v-model="dataentry.options"
                           filled
                           type="textarea" />
                </q-tab-panel>
                <q-tab-panel name="tabEntryInfo">

                </q-tab-panel>
                <q-tab-panel name="tabCascadeField">

                </q-tab-panel>
              </q-tab-panels>
```

For example, there are 3 q-tabs, if the user only want to let 2 of them to show, and 1 of them to hide after a dropdown option selected.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event @input about q-select, and we can trigger a model variable for every q-tab. It works for me

```
onDataSourceTypeChanged (event) {
  var dstype = this.datasource.datasourcetype
  if (dstype === 'datasourcetype.Customized') {
    this.dataentry.showOptionsTab = true
    this.dataentry.showDataEntryTab = false
    this.dataentry.showCasacdeFieldTab = false
  } else {
    this.dataentry.showOptionsTab = false
    this.dataentry.showDataEntryTab = true
    this.dataentry.showCasacdeFieldTab = true
  }
}
```